# Shorten a Long directory

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How do I Shorten a long directory?

I have this:

`http://localhost/project/moduleMes/message/sentMail.php`

to something like this
`sentMail.php` is this possible?

I'm not that familiar in manipulating directories, but my aim is to determine the `.action` of the form. If I have a `<form id="formMail" action="sentMail.php">` and if I get the action of this form by `alert(document.getElementById('formMail').action);` it displays `http://localhost/project/moduleMes/message/sentMail.php` but I only need the `sentMail.php`.

My solution is to use `split` and get the last array, but I want to know if there is a formal way to do get `sentMail.php` alone?

Any other options?

Comment: How about not storing your `sentMail.php` on `/project/moduleNes.message/`?

Comment: How about `document.getElementById('formMail').getAttribute('action');` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = document.getElementById('formMail').action; // or something else
var script_name = /[^\/].+\.php$/.exec(str)[0];
```

UPDATE: changed regexp

Comment: Are you shure about this? What if `action="otherDir/mail.php"` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:

```
var output = document.getElementById('formMail').action.split(/\/+/).pop();
```

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PgLN9/2/) which test out various values.

In case you are using jQuery:

```
var output = $('#formMail').attr('action').split(/\/+/).pop();
```